# Sort the table rows in the alphabetically order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am working on my JQuery script to add the row in the table. I want to sort the texts in the alphabetically order like A,B,C,D,E..etc.

When I try this:

```
var mylist = $('#tcM');
var listitems = mylist.find('tr');
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.alC').text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).find('.alC').text().toUpperCase());
});
```

It will not sort the data in the alphabetically order as it will show like this:

```
test1
test2
test new folder
test4
```

It should be:

```
test1
test2
test4
test new folder
```

I have also tried this:

```
$('#tcM .tBM').sort(sort_folder1).appendTo('.tBM');
function sort_folder1(a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Full code:

```
folder_html = "<tr id='"+unique_id+"' class='To' style='margin-top: 50px;'><td class='alT' style='width: 90%;'><div class='Zsjd8d' act='s'><div id='mMI' style='background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='' data-original-title='More'></div><i style='margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;' class='folder_icon'></i><div class='alC'>"+new_folder+"</div></div></td><td class='alQ'><div id='edit_folder' class='edit_icon' style='float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Edit Folder'></div><div id='delete_folder' class='trash_icon' style='display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Delete Folder'></div></div></td></tr>";
$('#tcM').append(folder_html);
```

Html:

```
<table id="tcM" class="table table-inbox table-hover" style="width: 98%; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;">
<tbody class="tBM" style="display: table-row-group;"><tr id="2T" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;">
<td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test1</div></div></td>
<td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr>
<tr id="hj" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test2</div></div></td>
<td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr>
<tr id="It" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test new folder</div></div></td>
<td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr>
<tr id="d5" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test4</div></div></td>
<td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

It is still showing the data in the same alphabetically order. I am unable to find out how to fix the issue.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arwnzu03/1/

Can you please show me an example how I can be able to set the texts in the alphabetically order for the rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does work. However since you work with a jQuery collection and not with a live collection the DOM isn't automatically updated. To do this append the elements back to your table, this will remove the old `<tr>` elements from where they where and append them to your `<table id="tcM">` tabble.

```js
var mylist = $('#tcM');
var listitems = mylist.find('tr');
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.alC').text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).find('.alC').text().toUpperCase());
});

mylist.append(listitems);
```

```css
.folder_icon {
    /* background-image: url(http://mail.workwithchrisonline.com/mail/u/0/images/label_grey_20dp.png); */
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.edit_icon {
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/edit_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.trash_icon {
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/delete_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tcM" class="table table-inbox table-hover" style="width: 98%; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"><tbody class="tBM" style="display: table-row-group;"><tr id="2T" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test1</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="hj" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test2</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="It" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test new folder</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="d5" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test4</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The reason `$('#tcM .tBM').sort(sort_folder1).appendTo('.tBM');` isn't working is because you select the `.tBM` elements inside `#tcM` which is the `<tbody>`. You should select your `<tr>`s.

```
$("#tcM tr").sort(sort_folder1).appendTo(".tBM");
```

The above should also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an example which sorts your table rows. However, if you're just doing a text compare, "test new folder" will come before "test1" because a blank space will sort before the '1' character.

```js
const myList = document.getElementById('tcM');
const listItems = myList.querySelectorAll('tr');

// Turn the list into an array for sorting
let listArray = [...listItems];
listArray.sort((a, b) => a.innerText.toLowerCase() < b.innerText.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);

// Replace the table contents
listArray.forEach(item => myList.appendChild(item));
```

```css
.folder_icon {
    /* background-image: url(http://mail.workwithchrisonline.com/mail/u/0/images/label_grey_20dp.png); */
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.edit_icon {
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/edit_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.trash_icon {
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/delete_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tcM" class="table table-inbox table-hover" style="width: 98%; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"><tbody class="tBM" style="display: table-row-group;"><tr id="2T" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test1</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="hj" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test2</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="It" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test new folder</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="d5" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test4</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: `myList.innerHTML=''` is superfluous: If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: You're right. I just tried it without clearing `myList` and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ed's solution already works perfectly. By playing around with it and using some ES6 syntax I found that you can shorten the script part even further. This will work with all modern browsers but not with the Internet Explorer.

Instead of `.appendChild()` I use `.append()` and I leave out the `innerHTML=''` bit, as the `<tr>`s will be moved and not copied anyway.

```js
// shortcut function qsa():
function qsa(s,c){ return [...(c||document).querySelectorAll(s)];}
// collect all TRs and sort them:
var trs=qsa('#tcM tbody tr').sort((a, b) => a.innerText.toLowerCase() < b.innerText.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);

// Replace the table contents
trs[0].parentNode.append(...trs);
```

```css
.folder_icon {
    /* background-image: url(http://mail.workwithchrisonline.com/mail/u/0/images/label_grey_20dp.png); */
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.edit_icon {
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/edit_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.trash_icon {
    background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/delete_black_20dp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tcM" class="table table-inbox table-hover" style="width: 98%; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"><tbody class="tBM" style="display: table-row-group;"><tr id="2T" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test1</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="hj" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test2</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="It" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test new folder</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr><tr id="d5" class="To" style="margin-top: 50px;"><td class="alT" style="width: 90%;"><div class="Zsjd8d" act="s"><div id="markMore_img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/more_vert_black_20dp.png);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 20px;width: 20px;height: 20px;display: flex;margin-left: 1px; /* vertical-align: middle; */float: left;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="More"></div><i style="margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 11px;display: inline-block;" class="folder_icon"></i><div class="alC">test4</div></div></td><td class="alQ"><div id="edit_folder" class="edit_icon" style="float: left;margin-left: 1px;margin-top: 2px;display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Folder"></div><div id="delete_folder" class="trash_icon" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 14px;margin-top: 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Folder"></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```